# Cannot login to my VM, it says I must grant compute.instances.setMetadata permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am a very new user of GCM using it to transfer some data between two cloud storage services.

Everything was going fine until just recently, and now I am unable to login to my VM.

When I try, I get the error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to SSH into this instance. You need the following IAM permission: compute.instances.setMetadata.

Currently trying to figure out how to enable it, but as my understanding of this platform is pretty remedial, I have not been able to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You will need to an an IAM role to your identity in Google Cloud IAM. You probably want to add the IAM role `Compute OS Login` or `Compute OS Admin Login`. This page has more details: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/set-up-oslogin